# The stepper form does not send data after clicking submit. MDBootstrap Laravel

Tags: laravel, mdbootstrap, stepper, formwizard, step

I'm using "laravel vue ui auth" to authentication, and all the functions are working. then I changed the form register using stepper from mdbootstrap. But the submit button doesn't work and the data doesn't perform the post action. There seems to be a flaw or error in the stepper, but I don't know what it is.
blade:

```
<ul method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" class="stepper linear">
                        @csrf
                        <li class="step active">
                            <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Personal Info</div>
                                <div class="step-new-content">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Via Sarah">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="step-actions">
                                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-primary next-step">CONTINUE</button>
                                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-secondary previous-step">BACK</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="step">
                            <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Login Information</div>
                            <div class="step-new-content">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="step-actions">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-primary m-0 mt-4" type="submit">{{ __('Register') }}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

controller:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    return view('auth.register');
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller method needs to be `public` not `protected`.
Also use `Request $request` in the arguments.

Here is code:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    // Validate request
    $user = User::create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'email' => $request->email,
        'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
    ]);

    return view('auth.register');
}
```

**Note:** Don't forget to use `Request` in the top of controller.

**Update:**

Wrap your `<ul>` with form. `<ul>` doesn't support `method` and `action` attributes.

Here is the final version:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
<ul class="stepper linear">
                        @csrf
                        <li class="step active">
                            <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Personal Info</div>
                                <div class="step-new-content">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="name">Full Name</label>
                                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Via Sarah">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                <div class="step-actions">
                                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-primary next-step">CONTINUE</button>
                                    <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-secondary previous-step">BACK</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="step">
                            <div class="step-title waves-effect waves-dark">Login Information</div>
                            <div class="step-new-content">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                                    @error('email')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                    @error('password')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="step-actions">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="waves-effect waves-dark btn btn-sm btn-primary m-0 mt-4" type="submit">{{ __('Register') }}</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: when I use <form> on the blade, the controller is working fine. the problem comes when I change the register form with stepper

Comment: So why you are using `<ul>` instead of `<form>` ? `<ul>` doesn't support `method`, `action` attributes

Comment: yes, it worked. Thank you.
but here I moved the submit button outside <ul>

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)